# How to disable Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I've recently introduced Apache CXF into my web-service handling module to allow me to use some advanced features that it offers.

Unfortunatelly I cannot find any kind of trigger to enable/disable using CXF in runtime. I got dozens of applications reusing parts of that module and I don't want all of them to use CXF in runtime only because its libraries are on the classpath. CXF, as great as it is introduces some bugs or alters the behaviour of the application significantly so I need a way to disable it where its not necessary.

Is there some kind of system property or something I can use so that the CXF libraries are ignored in the runtime?

Comment: I think it is not possible to change the classloader once loaded. What functions do you want to avoid? Maybe there is a workaround for some of them

Comment: Nothing specific, I would like the application to behave as if the cxf was not even on the classpath. Its for example messing with unit tests execution of related modules (jvm errors with cxf on the classpath), ant builds and so on

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way I found to switch between CXF and standard java jax-ws implementation is using appropriate provider, by setting either

```
Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

or

```
Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```